# XSL Dropdown Selected Attribute

Tags: xslt

I've seen similar questions and solutions on here but nothing I've tried has worked out. I'm trying to generate a drop-down list of month names with /result/startMonthName as the default selected option.

```
<select id="queryMonth">
<xsl:for-each select="/result/monthOptions/entry">
    <option value="{key + 1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:if test="/result/startMonthName">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </option>
</xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

However, the first month is always the initial selected.
The monthOptions result is a node of Values (month names) and keys (month integers from 0 to 11). I have tried with both xsl:if test="/result/startMonthName" and xsl:if test="/result/startMonth".

I have found that if the

```
<xsl:value-of select="value"/>
```

line is after the

```
<xsl:if test="/result/startMonthName">
    <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

then the last month is always the initial selected, but never the startMonth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `<xsl:if test="/result/startMonthName">` is doing is checking whether the `startMonthName` node exists, not what its value is.

You should probably be doing this...

```
<xsl:if test="value = /result/startMonthName">
```

Additionally, you do need to reverse the `xsl:if` and `xsl:value-of` statements, as it is considered an error to create an attribute on an element after you have created a child node.

```
<option value="{key + 1}">
    <xsl:if test="value = /result/startMonthName">
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</option>
```

(What was probably happening is that the XSLT processor is chosen to simply not add the attribute in the case you had the statements the other way around, rather than flag the error, resulting in no options being selected. The browser will then just select the first option by default).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I previously had the `test="value = result/startMonthName"` but not before the `xsl:value-of`.